# Next.js: Link to element in a component on the same page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jsx

I am working on my first Next.js project and I have a one-page website. I already have done the navigation component, but now I need to manage links.

How to add `<Link />` component that will refer to elements (in my case `<section>`) in other components (I mean something like in pure HTML with element id:

`<a href="#about">About us</a>`)?

Is it possible to change the URL slug when the scroll position is on the specific element (e.g. when the user scrolls to the About us section the slug will be *domain.com/**about*** and when the user will scroll down on the same page to Contact section the URL slug will be *domain.com/**contact***)?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that behavior using what you said above and it will work.

something like this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-babycat-4zoqv?file=/pages/index.js

```
 <div>
      These are the links
      <Link href="#about">
        <a>About</a>
      </Link>
      <Link href="#contact">
        <a>contact</a>
      </Link>
      <div
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          height: "2000px",
          marginTop: 800,
          background: "#ff0"
        }}
      >
        <section ref={aboutRef} id="about" style={{ ...sectionStyle }}>
          About
        </section>
        <section
          ref={contactRef}
          style={{ ...sectionStyle, background: "red" }}
          id="contact"
        >
          Contact
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! One more question, is it possible to remove the **#** from the slug (change ***domain.com/#about*** to ***domain.com/about***)?